# Husky e commitlint não funcionam antes do comando git commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

Foram instalados os pacotes husky e commitlint a um projeto NodeJS com a intenção de adicionar Hooks aos comandos `git commit` para manter um mesmo guia de estilo nas mensagens de `commit`.

Entretanto os Hooks não estão sendo acionados, permitindo que mesmo as mensagens mal formatadas de `commit` fossem executadas.

OBS:
Todos os passos do [guia de instalação](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint) já foram seguidos corretamente, e o arquivo `package.json` já está com o trecho necessário para acionar o hook:

```
// package.json
{
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
}
```

**Dados do ambiente:**

- Linux: 16.04.1-Ubuntu
- Git: 2.7
- Node: v12.18.3
- Husky: 4.3.7
- @commitlint/cli: 11.0.0
- @commitlint/config-conventional: 11.0.0

Answer (score 1):

No [repositório do pacote Husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) tem um trecho não muito evidente, onde menciona que a versão minima do Git instalada deve ser 2.13.0

> Verify that your version of Git is >=2.13.0.

E para fazer a atualização do Git no Ubuntu, basta executar os seguintes comandos:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
git --version
```

Após fazer a atualização do Git, reinicie o computador e faça os testes novamente.
Espero ter ajudado.